# Плохо ли использовать get() и set() методы?

Tags: c++, ооп, методы

Плохо ли использовать `get()/set()` методы?

Прочитал довольно много статей, мнения некоторых разработчиков (косвенно), отрывки из книг.
Кто-то 'за', кто-то "категорически против". Плохо с точки зрения бизнес-технологий или с точки зрения логики ООП (инкапсуляции)?

Тогда как нам взаимодействовать с полями-членами класса?

Cлышал, что лучше всего использовать конструкторы. Так ли это?

Comment: вы бы хоть привели примеры этих категорически против, и категорически за. Любой инструмент надо использовать к месту, а не потому что он есть

Comment: Да, хотелось бы увидеть конкретные примеры и цитаты, что там за "против" такое. Странно. Может речь чисто об инициализации скрытых полей класса и вопрос в том, делать ли её напрямую или через сеттеры?

Comment: @CrazyElf Дэвид Уэста "Object Thinking".
P.S. ссылку на второй материал почему-то не получается оформить =>
"Егор Бугаенко — Объектно-ориентированное вранье"

Comment: Если при присваивании (чтении) нового значения полю нужно проверять допустимость нового значения, то используйте set. (при чтении теоретически возможна ситуация, что объект находится в unconsistent state и вместо получения значения поля желательно кинуть exception (или что-то похожее сделать))

Comment: Смешались в кучу люди, кони... *"бизнес-технологий"* - это buzz-word, get()/set() можно использовать и вне контекста ООП, а конструкторы - это специальный метод класса, где происходит вся инициализация совершенно независимо от наличия / отсутствия get()/set().

Comment: @user7860670 Из-за правки моего текста другим человеком, смысл кардинально изменился. Общий смысл заключался в следующем 1)"Хорошо ли использовать `get/set` методы для передачи смысловой нагрузки класса?";2) Инициализация полей предпочтительней(лучше) задавать через конструкторы, либо все же через метод `set()` ?"- исходя из рекомендаций тех,кто "против".

Comment: Чужие правки можно отклонять или править самому. 1) все средства хороши 2) в С++ инициализация возможна только в конструкторе, через `set` можно только что-то присвоить после инициализации.

Answer (score 2):

Плохо использовать get()/set() методы, когда это ненужно. Если просто нужно присвоить полю значение или прочитать его значение, то зачем программировать лишние действия?

Использовать get()/set() не может быть плохо ни с точки зрения бизнес-технологий, ни с точки зрения логики ООП. Их нужно использовать по мере необходимости.

Ещё бывают случаи, когда другие классы (бибилиотеки) требуют, чтобы члены-данные были реализованы как свойства (через get()/set()).

Конструкторы никак не связаны с get()/set().

Comment: Скорее всего имеется в виду, что пропертя надо устанавливать только через конструктор (получаем тогда "немутабельный" объект). Ну а `get` да, с конструктором никак не связать.

Comment: @u_mulder Да. Исправил немного текст.